# What are Windows 8.1 Square 30x30 Target Size Logos used for?

Tags: windows-8, manifest, windows-8.1, assets

In the Package.appxmanifest on my Windows 8.1 project, the Visual Assets has a section called Square 30x30 Logo in the Tile Images and Logos category.

I know how to upload the Scale images and how to name them (imageName.scale-180.png etc), but I don't know what the Target Size images are for, or how to name them in the assets folder.

Where and when are Target Size images used? Are they used instead of the Scaled images? Any insight in this would be greatly appreciated.

(I can't post an image to clearly illustrate the assets in the manifest, as I require more points, so apologises for the lack of image.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same question, then found this;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh965372.aspx#target_size

These images are primarily used outside of WinRT/the Windows Store, for things like file association icons and protocol icons. That's why the sizes map to the usual sizes for older Win32 icons.

You can apparently name the images like this for automatic inclusion/assignment in the manifest file;

targetsize-

Examples:

targetsize-16
targetsize-96

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I had searched high and low and couldn't find an explanation for them. But now I know the file name format, I can make them and add them to my solution.